# Is there any object that I can use as FIFO with event for poping data out?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, queue

I need to have a FIFO object that when it has an element, it generate an event or make a call back to inform that an element is available. As far as I can see, std:queue doesn't support this.

In my case, I have two threads that one thread generate data and other thread needs to consume them.

The speed that first thread generate data is not fixed and hence I need to have a buffer that store the data so the other thread can read and process them in a relatively constant manner.

I know how to implement the writer, but in the reader side, If I poll the queue, then I am loosing some processing power to check the queue status and I am wondering if there is any better way of doing this?

## Edit 1

It is not about thread safety of queue, but std::queue is working based on polling, but I need something that is event based. std::queue is not event based and will not make a call back when a new data is available.

Comment: Are you looking for the appropriate STL container or a pattern?

Comment: @RawN Any solution, apparently, if STL already has a container, it would be better, otherwise how to implement one.

Comment: There's queue and then there's deque. If you are thinking about inheriting from the existing class template - don't.

Comment: @RawN Both std::queue and std::deque are polling base, but I need something that is event base. I need something that inform reader that a new data is available and when there is no data available, the reader is waiting for an event or wait on a mutex and so on, so no overhead from the reader polling the queue to find if there is any data.

Comment: I doubt there is such a thing as an event base STL container. You are probably looking for a design pattern or a variation. I think there is no such thing as an out of the box event in c++.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you may very well use C++ `std::condition_variables` for notification between threads about the availability of item in a queue and then call the callback.

The code will look something like this.  Here the Main Thread acts as a generator thread and Receive Thread acts as a consumer thread

```
std::condition_variable Cv_;
std::mutex Mutex_;
std::queue<int> qVal;

void callback() {
    cout << "Callback Called with queue Value =>" << qVal.front() << endl;
    qVal.pop();
}
void ReceiveThread() {

    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<mutex> Lock(Mutex_);
        Cv_.wait(Lock);
        callback();
    }
}

int main() {
    thread thrd(ReceiveThread);
    int pushVal = 1;
    while (1) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        qVal.push(pushVal);
        cout << "Signalling for callback with value = " << pushVal<< endl;
        pushVal++;
        Cv_.notify_all();
    }
}
```

I haven't added any exit condition in the while loop which you might want to have.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, as the std::queue is not thread safe, is this code works properly, as I can not see any guard that the std::queue is used only by one thread at any time. Am I wrong?

Comment: @mans : No sir you're not wrong. you need to guard the main thread before putting things into the queue with "Mutex_".  I didn't do that because my code was mainly intended to show how you could achieve what you're trying  to do.

Comment: Thanks, it is very appreciated. Can I use the same mutex  (Mutex_) for guarding access to std:queue or I need a new mutex?

Comment: @mans you can use lock guard for same mutex as `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lgm(Mutex_)`

Answer (score 0):

The `std::queue::push()` function do not have any placeholder inside it such that we can simple put our `call_back function` reference in it so that after successfully inserting element inside `queue` the `call_back function` would get invoked.

```
std::queue::push(data)
{
    //add data to internal container

    //placeholder section--------
    //invoke call_back function or event.
    //placeholder section--------
}
```

So in the absence of such placeholder, we can try automatic invocation of `call_back function` or some event using RAII.

Suppose we wrap our actual data inside a `struct` which will help us in notifications. Then, we will be required to indirectly access the actual data via objects of this `struct`.

```
struct data_notifier
{
    //the true data.
    int actual_data;

    data_notifier(int data) : actual_data(data)
    {
        //signal event queue_full       
        //or
        //call a call_back function.
    }
}

int actual_data = 90;
std::queue<data_notifier*> q;
q.push(new data_notifier(actual_data));
```

Now, only problem is: before an instance of `data_notifier` gets properly inserted in `queue` as a reference/pointer, our `call_back` or event would get invoked. So having the event got invoked, reader will try to read the data but will not get the data from the queue simply because data is not yet persisted inside the queue.
So, such guarantee of data properly getting persisted inside queue is only possible after the function `std::queue::push()` returns which can and will happen inside `Writer` function.

```
//event_full is a manual event which needs to be signalled and non-signalled manually.

void Writer()
{
    while(1)
    {
        //[1] wait for mutex_queue
        //[2] myqueue.push(data);
        //[3] data is now persisted so signal event_full
        //[4] release mutex_queue
    }
}

void Reader()
{   
    while(1) 
    {
        //[1] wait for event_full (so no polling)

        //[2] wait for mutex_queue

        //[3] --- access queue ---
        if(myqueue.size() != 0)
        {
            //process myqueue.front()
            //myqueue.pop();
        }
        if(myqueue.size() == 0)
        {
            //reset event_full      
            //so as long as queue has data, Reader can process it else needs to wait. 
        }
        //[3] --- access queue ---

        //[4] release mutex_queue   
    }
}
```